# We played table tennis yesterday. Oftentimes, when I smashed the ball to him, he "would/used to" return the ball by touching the ball - correct?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

**Example 1**

> (1) We played table tennis yesterday. Oftentimes, when I smashed the ball to him, he **would/used to** return the ball by touching the ball.

> (2) We played table tennis yesterday. Oftentimes, when I smashed the ball to him, he **returned** the ball by touching the ball.

**Example 2**

> (1) We played table tennis yesterday. Most of the time, he **would/used to** hit the ball softly.

> (2) We played table tennis yesterday. Most of the time, he **hit** the ball softly.

When we talk about a specific event, can we use **would** or **used to** or do we just need to use the simple past tense?

Comment: _Used to_ is definitely not appropriate; it refers to someone's habitual behaviour during a (long) period of time in the past. Yes, I know yesterday's game is 'in the past', but it's recent and comparatively short.

Comment: Worth noting that 'oftentimes' is very much an Americanism; it may be replaced by 'often', which is more usual in non-American English.

Comment: "Oftentimes" was much more common before 1900 in both US and UK English. Nowadays it is relatively uncommon, though used more in US than UK.

Comment: We do not say oftentimes in the US in contemporary speech. generally speaking. Also, smashed the ball **at him** is wrong. Also, return the ball by touching it makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary definition of "oftentimes" misleadingly implies that it is equal in usage to "often."  That is incorrect.  While the meaning *is* technically the same, the idiomatic usage is not.  "Oftentimes" implies multiple occasions, not simply a single occasion.

If you had been playing table tennis with the same opponent over a period of days, or better still, weeks or months or years, then the term "oftentimes" would be more fitting.  Within the context of a single day or evening, use "often."

The expression "used to" in the context of a past action is applied to an action of a habitual nature, something that is routine or the usual practice for that time.  "Used to" also means that this habitual action has changed, is in the past, and is no longer the current practice.  Something that happened as recently as "yesterday" would rarely qualify as sufficiently in the past to accept the usage of "used to" (it would in some contexts apply, but not here with table tennis tactics that have not changed).

Given these principles, a corrected wording would be as follows:

- *"We played table tennis yesterday. **Often,** when I smashed the ball to him, he **would** return the ball by touching it."*

This would also be acceptable:

- *"We played table tennis yesterday. **Often,** when I smashed the ball to him, he **returned** the ball by touching it."*

The examples using "most of the time" in place of "often" are both correct as long as "used to" is avoided, i.e. use this form:

- *"We played table tennis yesterday. Most of the time, he **would** hit the ball softly."*

Comment: Is "We played table tennis yesterday. He would often return the ball by touching it when I smashed the ball to him" 

equal to "We played table tennis yesterday. Often, when I smashed the ball to him, he returned the ball by touching it."?

Comment: The meaning is essentially the same.  You are correctly setting the reordered clause apart with commas, as it is not the most natural order.  The modal past (would return) and the simple past (returned) carry essentially the same meaning in this context, with the modal coloring the action slightly as being the result of his preference or choice--i.e. something he wanted to do, and the simple past expressing it simply as a matter of fact.

Answer (score 4):

You have established a time frame with your first statement. Everything you say subsequently applies to the game (or games) of table tennis played yesterday. The term '*oftentimes*' just isn't appropriate in this case. It doesn't mean the same as 'most of the time' - it refers to a trend over time or multiple occasions. So neither of your options in example 1 is correct.

Likewise, the terms 'would' and 'used to' are used to refer to trends over time. They just aren't appropriate.

When referring to something that happened in the past, having established the event as you have, just use the simple past tense "he hit". You could also use "he was hitting", which can better indicate an action throughout a period.

Answer (score 0):

Only "would" is correct.

Both "used to" and "would" refer to repeated behaviour in the past. They can also both be used when contrasting patterns of behaviour in the past to patterns of behaviour now.

Further, "would" can refer to a repeated action any time in the past, without indicating a pattern of behaviour nor contrast with the present. "Used to" does not have this function. In your context of the table tennis game yesterday, this is the function you want, so only "would" is correct.

Answer (score -1):

"Used to" can refer to a repeated practice (such as a habit) in the past that has ceased. [M-W's definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/used%20to) is:

> used to say something happened repeatedly in the past but does not happen now

The table-tennis game was relatively short-lived, so "used to" would be inappropriate.

---

Example 1

"Oftentimes" should not be used for something that occurred over a short duration, such as a table-tennis game. Furthermore, writing "the ball" three times is repetitive. You could instead write the sentences so:

> We played table tennis yesterday. Often, when I smashed the ball to him, he would return it by touching it.

> We played table tennis yesterday. Often, when I smashed the ball to him, he returned it by touching it.

---

Example 2

Either version is correct as long as you avoid "used to".